# Use camera for both native and web app with Ionic/AngularJS and Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the Camera, and I would like to know if you have any exemple on how to make it work on both web / native.

I have this piece of code, borrowed from the ng-cordova doc :

```
    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 100,
            targetHeight: 100,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            // Success! Image data is here
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }
```

When I use it, it works well with my device, but catch an error with the web version

```
ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
```

That's why I ask if you have any good way to do that. I could simulate a click on an hidden input, but it doesn't look pretty. If you have any idea :)

Answer (score 4):

You could provide an implementation for the camera access for both Cordova and standard browser. The standard browser implementation could be realized using this

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

[W3 draft](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/)

and to check, whether you're running in an app or in browser, you could use

```
ionic.Platform.platform()
```

documented [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

Comment: Do you think I should wrap it in a factory ? I'm pretty new to angular/cordova/ionic

Comment: Yes, you should have your `$scope.takePicture()`, accessible by a button on your template, executing a function in a factory.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I wonder if it doesn't already exists, I can't be the only one thinking about that.

Comment: accessing the webcam via HTML5 is not very established yet and in its early stages.

Comment: Well, not really. It was on an old project, so I remember having used a regular input file which I hide, and when the user click on an icon, I check if on browser or on mobile device and trigger the right action.

At this time, it was the only solution I found. Maybe is a better solution around here now.